# Incorrect GLSurfaceView positioning

Tags: android, opengl-es, position, glsurfaceview

I have a GLSurfaceView with a renderer assigned to it. On this view, I draw images which seem to be offset to the left compared to where I have requested that they be drawn on it. This problem has only arisen since I switched from Canvas-based rendering, which rendered the images in their correct positions, to OpenGL 1.0 rendering, which doesn't.

I have read through my code and have found absolutely nothing that could be causing this. What frustrates me is that I know there is nothing wrong with the positions I set using my code, but the problem still persists.

Now, here's the best part of it all. When I pause the application by pressing the home button, and then restart the application through the task manager, the positions are fixed and are exactly how they should be, which leads me to believe that the problem isn't with the positions I set using my code, but how I've set up my surface view. I've checked the dimensions in the onSurfaceChanged() parameters only to find that they are always as they should be, which leaves me even more confused.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: you failed to add any codes.

Comment: There's too many parts which involve drawing objects to the screen, and how can the same code produce two different results as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging through my project, I discovered I was setting positions based on the dimensions of the GLSurfaceView before `onSurfaceChanged` had been called in the `onSurfaceCreated` method, therefore the width/height of the view at this point was 0 which affected the positions of my objects on the screen.

I feel really stupid now.